# C changing variable and array value

Tags: c, variables, scope

At first code a[0] becomes 31 but in the second one a still 55. Can someone explain me the difference? What is the difference between changing a variable's and array's value in a function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int h(int x[]);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int a[0] = 55;
    h(a);
    printf("%d", a[0]);
    return 0;
}

int h(int x[]) {
   x[0] = 31; 
}
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int h(int x);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int a= 55;
    h(a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}

int h(int x) {
   x = 31; 
}
```

And What about this code? This array is changed. I am really confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int h(int x[], int length);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[]= {5, 5, 5, 5};
    h(a, 4);
    printf("Array After Function Call\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       printf("%d ", a[i]);
   }
    return 0;
}

int h(int x[], int length) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       x[i] += x[i];
   }
   printf("Array in Function\n");
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       printf("%d ", x[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[0]` is an array of *zero* elements. The value inside the brackets is the size, the number of elements, not the value of the top index.

Comment: `int a[0] = 55;` is not allowed in Standard C (zero-sized arrays are not allowed; and arrays can only be initialized by brace-enclosed list). Suggest changing your compile switches to behave in standard mode

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Deleted my comment. Confused `a[0]` with `a[]`. I will add a comment to the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And any decent book should have mentioned that arguments to functions are passed *by value*, meaning the value in the call is *copied* into the local function argument variable.

Modifying this local variable will only modify the local copy, not the value used in the call to the function.

One can overcome this problem by emulating *pass by reference*, which is done by passing a pointer to the variable:

```
void f(int *x)
{
    *x = 123;  // Dereference the pointer, to set the value of where it's pointing
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    f(&a);  // Pass a pointer to the variable a
}
```

This is really what's happening in the first program you show, you pass a pointer, and modify the value of where the pointer is pointing (the zero-sized array notwithstanding).

---

It seems that one of your major confusions is about your "array" argument.

When you declare a function as

```
void f(int a[]);
```

you don't actually declare an array argument: The compiler will treat it as a *pointer* and parse it as

```
void f(int *a);
```

Another point is that when you use array indexing, like

```
x[i] += x[i];
```

you are actually dereferencing the pointer, and write the values to the memory where the pointer is pointing. In fact, for any pointer or array `x` and index `i`, the expression `x[i]` is exactly equal to `*(x + i)`.

Comment: What you think about the last code

Comment: passing the pointer to variable uses "side effects" which is not always good. In most circumstances is better to return the value https://godbolt.org/z/vUEuHV